# Office script "failed to load [code] [library]" error

Tags: typescript, office-scripts, excel-online

I have a class that should keep the excel table's values as a property. If I put `getValues()` inside the class constructor, the script fails with *failed to load [code] [library]* error (full message from editor console output).

```
function main(wkb: ExcelScript.Workbook){
  const tbl = wkb.getTable('test')
  const info = new Info(tbl)
}

class Info {
  table: ExcelScript.Table
  vals: string[][]

  constructor(table: ExcelScript.Table){
    this.table = table
    // failing here, line commented for workaround
    this.vals = table.getValues() as unknown[][] as string[][]
  }

  getVals(){
    // this will work (if not called from the constructor)
    this.vals = this.table.getRange().getValues() as unknown[][] as string[][]
  }
}
```

As a workaround, I'm calling the `getVals()` method after class instance initialization, but I would like to avoid that additional call.

What I'm doing wrong here? Is it something related to how TypeScript works (just started learning) or something specific to Office Script API?

Comment: I believe this is a restriction related to how the constructor can be used. You can see additional information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68659405/office-scripts-class-constructor-does-not-work

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting may be an office scripts error.

In addition to the option you listed above, you can modify the constructor and provide the table values when you create the object. This will allow you to assign the table values in the constructor:

```
function main(wkb: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  const tbl : ExcelScript.Table = wkb.getTable('test');
  const tblValues: (string | number | boolean)[][] = tbl.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getValues();
  const info = new Info(tbl,tblValues);
  console.log(info.getVals());
}

class Info {
  private table: ExcelScript.Table;
  private vals: string[][];

  constructor(table: ExcelScript.Table, vals: (string|number|boolean)[][]) {
    this.table = table;
    this.vals = vals as string[][];
  }

  getVals() {
    return this.vals;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a current limitation of the Office Scripts API. At the moment, avoid calling Office Script APIs inside of class constructors.

One way around this limitation is to create a method that calls Office Script APIs:

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook)
{
  const info = getInfo(workbook);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(info.getVals()));
}

function getInfo(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  const tbl: ExcelScript.Table = workbook.getTable('test');
  const tblValues: (string | number | boolean)[][] = tbl.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getValues();
  const info = new Info(tbl, tblValues);
  return info;
}

class Info {
  private table: ExcelScript.Table;
  private vals: string[][];

  constructor(table: ExcelScript.Table, vals: (string | number | boolean)[][]) {
    // avoid calling Office Script APIs inside of class constructors.
    this.table = table;
    this.vals = vals as string[][];
  }

  getVals() {
    return this.vals;
  }
}
```

This method can be added as a static method of the class:

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook)
{
  const info = Info.create(workbook);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(info.getVals()));
}

class Info {
  private table: ExcelScript.Table;
  private vals: string[][];

  constructor(table: ExcelScript.Table, vals: (string | number | boolean)[][]) {
    // avoid calling Office Script APIs inside of class constructors.
    this.table = table;
    this.vals = vals as string[][];
  }

  static create(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    const tbl: ExcelScript.Table = workbook.getTable('test');
    const tblValues: (string | number | boolean)[][] = tbl.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getValues();
    const info = new Info(tbl, tblValues);
    return info;
  }

  getVals() {
    return this.vals;
  }
}
```

Generally, in terms of programming best practices it may be convenient for constructors to avoid containing complex logic.